# Lotka-Volterra unique existence of solution in $[0,T[$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that exists an unique solution for the Lotka-Volterra problem for $t \in [0, T[$.
With the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem I could only show that exists an interval of unique solution, but I don't know how to argument that $0$ is in this interval and the interval is positive.

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
\\x'(t) = x(t)(a-by(t))
\\y'(t) = y(t)(-c+dx(t))
\\x(0) = x_0 > 0
\\y(0) = y_0 >0 
\end{array}\right.$$

as $a, b, c, d > 0$

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have written down is an Initial Value Problem, with an initial condition at t=0. Now if you apply the [Picard–Lindelöf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) theorem (or Cauchy-Lipschitz), you automatically get the existence of a unique solution in an open interval $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ around 0. Hence, 0 is certainly in the interval of existence, as well as a bit of positive time.